# Application vs. page

Tags: facebook

I have registered an application for a website of mine. This is used for placing a like button, adding posts to visitors' streams, etc.

But this application does not show up anywhere and it does not seem that people can find and 'like' it.

So I created a page for this website/community.

Can I somehow connect these two, so that the existing 'likes', 'fans', etc. are moved to this new page? Or am I supposed to have and maintain both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Website** and a **Facebook Page about your Website** are two separate entities. Their Likes counts will be separated and there is no way to merge them.

A lot of people make the choice to only promote the **Facebook Page about your Website** as that allows them to share things with fans on facebook and to be visible to facebook visitors.
When making this choice, it's better to display on your website a like button targeting your facebook page instead of a like button targeting your website's url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so and I searched it for I while cause I too wanted to connect these but did't find A way for this.
So its better to maintain them both simultaneously.